# MySQL: str_to_date multiple formats

Tags: mysql, case, str-to-date

I have a ETL cleanup project where I have a unioned date column that includes formats such as "2014-10-14" and "10/14/2014 12:00:00 AM". I am trying to find a slick way I can convert them all using a str_to_date function either in a case statement or some other way to help determine which format it is and then convert it to a date.

So far all my efforts have failed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

`str_to_date` will return `NULL` if the particular conversion fails, so you can try doing one first. If the result is `NULL`, try the other format.

For example:

```
coalesce(
  str_to_date(create_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
  str_to_date(create_date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'),
  str_to_date(create_date, '%d/%b/%Y %H:%i:%s')
)
```